# Chrome Cache issue - Angularjs Web application

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I am developing an angularjs web application and facing some cache related issues as follows:

When any changes are made in the angularjs code and pushed to the server, the changes don't reflect in the application unless the users clears cache. This is because my html files are cached.

I cannot disable cache or use cache busting links for all the html pages as the application is huge and performance gets effected due to this.
I have even used :
 in my index.html

One solution we found was versioning of files using cache buster(angular-cache-buster) links, but then the latest versioned file is also not getting loaded in CHROME.
Example:
my graph.html loads as follows:

> abc123.abc123.com/scripts/components/dashboard/hcp/views/login.html?cacheBuster=Sprint_5_2017_2

The next time i make changes in this file cache buster changes to may be:

> abc123.abc123.com/scripts/components/dashboard/hcp/views/login.html?cacheBuster=Sprint_7_2017_3

But the changed URL also doesn't load in chrome as well as it says "(from disk cache in)" in size column in networks tab as attached in the screenshot.
[image]

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Thanks.